# JavaScript issue: setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout, jquery-hover

I'm trying to make a moving panel using JavaScript and jQuery.

I made this [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JV7w8/3/), the JS part look like this:

```
$("nav.nav").hover(function(){
    $("nav.nav").animate({left:'-5px'},100,"swing");
  },
  function(){
    $("nav.nav").animate({left:'-170px'},100,"swing");
  });
```

As you can see, it's working, but I want to add a delay when I leave the panel because, some time, I leave the panel for 1 pixel by mistake and it's annoying.

I tried to use `setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds);` like so:

```
$("nav.nav").hover(function(){
    $("nav.nav").animate({left:'-5px'},100,"swing");
  }, setTimeout(function(){
      $("nav.nav").animate({left:'-170px'},100,"swing");
  },10));
```

(The callback function in the timeout) but it's not working, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using jQuery's `.delay()` (combined with `.stop(true)`) which handles the timer stuff for you automatically:

```
$("nav.nav").hover(function () {
    $("nav.nav").stop(true).animate({left: '-5px'}, 100, "swing");
},function () {
    $("nav.nav").stop(true).delay(1000).animate({left: '-170px'}, 100, "swing");
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LuNHR/

Comment: It should be noted that delay(s) wouldn't be reseted here. Try to hover in/out many times as quick as possible in row to see what i mean

Comment: From the jQuery delay page:

The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the function inside the hover out function like this

```
var tOut = null;
$("nav.nav").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(tOut); //Clear timout so it doesn't animate back when hovering
    $("nav.nav").animate({
        left: '-5px'
    }, 100, "swing");
},function () {
    tOut = setTimeout(function () {
        $("nav.nav").animate({
            left: '-170px'
        }, 100, "swing");
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/JV7w8/4/)

Comment: Thank you Anton ... So i'm not using the callback function of the hover method anymore ? That's interesting !
EDIT : Forget it, I misread your code

Comment: Why using manual `setTimeout()` rather than `.delay()` and `.stop()` which are built into jQuery and work with animaations?

Comment: @jfriend00 ah thats true, settimeout was the first thing that came to my head